Finding Mean of Y_Var user input in Shiny using Plotly
I am hitting a roadblock in trying to find the mean value of the Y Axis of user input in plotly. I am making a shiny app and I need to be able to allow users to select different combinations of variables and manipulate the graph. Everything I have seen does not produce an average but sum of the variable which is not useful.
Data is the public use files of the Well-Being and Basic Needs Survey.
https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/HMCA/studies/38759/datadocumentation
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)



    ui <- fluidPage(
     titlePanel("WBNS"),
      sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("x_var", "X-axis variable:", 
                  choices = names(NumericSet)),
      selectInput("y_var", "Y-axis variable:", 
                  choices = names(NumericSet), selected = "Q27"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("plot")
       )
     )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        # This value is non-numeric so I can not apply any form of function to it.
        plot_ly(data = NumericSet, x = ~get(input$x_var), y =~get(input$y_var), 
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>%
      layout(title = 'Interactive Plot with WNBS Dataset', 
             xaxis = list(title = input$x_var), yaxis = list(title = input$y_var))
     })
    }


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`


Welocme to SO!  Do you want the mean value of the y variable (as in your title) or the mean value of the y axis [range] (as in your text)?  What do you want to do with the value when you have obtained it?  Add it to the graph some how?  Display it in another output widget?  Please provide more detail.
